# array[1] does not show up as null

Tags: c#, arrays, string, if-statement, null

I am having trouble getting the value of inputArray[1] to come up as a null value for my if statements.

Here is a look at the code:

```
static void GetInput()
    {
       string input = Console.ReadLine();
       string[] inputArray = input.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        switch (inputArray[0])
        {
            case "exit":
                System.Console.WriteLine(inputArray[0]);
                Console.WriteLine("Exiting...");
                break;
            case "help":
                System.Console.WriteLine(inputArray[0]);
                Help();
                GetInput();
                break;
            case "openall":
                if (inputArray[1] != null) ;
                {
                    System.Console.WriteLine(inputArray[0] + " " + inputArray[1]);
                    fileExt = inputArray[1];
                    OpenFiles();
                    GetInput();
                }
                break;                         
        }
    }
```

Now I have tried many ways other than if (inputArray[1] != null); but nothing seem to work so I know there is something in my knowledge of programming that I am missing right now.

I am getting this error:
Index was outside the bounds of the array.

All help is appreciated!

Comment: what is the string in input?

Comment: Whats the input you are providing in the input variable? You are not giving space in between two words of input variable. You should check the length first of the array and then check null.

Comment: Keep in mind, you have a **stray** semicolon at the end of your `if` statement you're worried about. Once you get your index out of range error fixed, this will cause the if statement to do nothing and the block underneath will execute every time.

Comment: Wow, hard to believe I pulled that very mistake I make fun of my friend for!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to test the length of the array, before you check if it is null.

So change this

```
if (inputArray[1] != null)
```

to something like

```
if (inputArray.Length > 1 && inputArray[1] != null)
```

[C# Array Length](http://www.dotnetperls.com/array-length)

As mentioned in the comments, the more correct code would be to test for

```
if (inputArray.Length > 1)
```

as `inputArray[1] != null` would never be true.

Comment: i think it will never be null, because he is using `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`

Comment: The null check is pointless ... it will never be null.

Comment: Noted, will change the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use `if(inputArray.length > 1)` instead of `if (inputArray[1] != null)`

Answer (score 2):

I just want to add one thing in your code.

This condition inputArray[1] != null will always occur if the inputArray contains more than or equal two element. Because if you are splitting the array it won't return 'null' and you have already specified RemoveEmptyEntries, so just check the length as mentioned in the previous answers. No need to check either its null or empty.

Answer (score 1):

I was checking your code, if your input is something like "open xxx" then  it will work fine , There must be a space between two words that you write because of that you use

```
   input.Spli(new char{' '} )
```

however it's better to check the array length before try to obtain any array element .

```
 if (inputArray.Length > [Array element index that you want to obtain ] ) 
            { 
                //TO DO 
            } 
            else 
            { 
                // TO DO
            }
```

Please keep in mind that your input string has to contian many seperate words that are seperated with spaces otherwise if your input string not contains many seperate word then your inputarray will have only one element